# Can I use ffmpeg to encode a procedurally generated video for livestream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a python script that continuously generates images (frames of a video).

I would normally save these images to files and then convert them to a video with ffmpeg using the command line. What additional steps are required to adapt this workflow for livestreaming?

Instead of saving the frames to files I would like to stream them to, say, YouTube, and my script could potentially run indefinitely generating frames of the video.

I'm looking for general guidelines so I can Google more details myself. I assume video platforms like YouTube have some API where I can send data for livestreaming. I have no idea what type of data format such API would expect, but I assume that just sending every single frame to the API is not how this is done.

Would I need to encode my frames in memory using some library? Can I use ffmpeg for that?

Comment: Have your script create a y4m stream, print it to stdout, and pipe that to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stream to YouTube from ffmpeg through RTMP.

For the output argument in your ffmpeg command, simply pass the YouTube RTMP address you intend to stream to, followed by your unique YouTube stream key.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> [additional arguments] -f flv rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAM_KEY
```

Note that YouTube may not recognize a stream unless it has accompanying audio; you can use the `anullsrc` filter in ffmpeg to produce an empty audio stream.

You will want to adjust the bitrate and other arguments to hit a balance of quality and what your computer and network can handle.

More info on streaming with ffmpeg:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites

As commented by @szatmary, you can pipe the raw frames to stdout, and have ffmpeg read it from stdin.

I was able to generate a livestream on my personal YouTube channel. It is looping red, green, blue frames changing color each second: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfWbDwrmCYA

I achieved it using the following Python script (depends on Pillow):

```
import os
import itertools
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor

colors = itertools.cycle([ImageColor.getrgb('red'), ImageColor.getrgb('green'), ImageColor.getrgb('blue')])

while True:
    color = next(colors)
    for i in range(30):
        os.write(1, Image.new('RGBA', [640, 360], color).tobytes())
```

And I then ran this in my terminal with both the script and ffmpeg in my PATH:

```
python3 script.py | \
ffmpeg \
-f rawvideo \
-vcodec rawvideo \
-s 640x360 \
-pix_fmt rgba \
-r 30 \
-i - \
-f lavfi \
-i anullsrc \
-c:v libx264 \
-b:v 1M \
-f flv \
rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAM_KEY
```

The above is executable; here is a pastebin with comments next to each argument describing them (not executable): https://pastebin.com/3G2y0tjm

Two final things to note:

1. I attempted to use the Pillow ImageMode `'RGB'` which I assumed would correspond with the ffmpeg `pix_fmt rgb8`, but that produced corrupted frames. Make sure that the two pixel formats match.
2. YouTube complained about ffmpeg streaming faster than real-time fps (~350fps on a '30fps' stream). You may want some way to include a sleep function or something and tune it to match your desired fps.

Sources:

- Adapted original ffmpeg arguments from blog post: https://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg
- Comments by @szatmary and @llogan about YouTube requiring audio and including anullsrc: [How to livestream a webcam to YouTube with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540004/how-to-livestream-a-webcam-to-youtube-with-ffmpeg#comment101585523_57540004)