# I have hosted a motion camera web server how to I send the feed to a .com website through port forwarding

Tags: raspberry-pi, motion

I have hosted a motion camera web server how to I send the feed to a .com website through port forwarding or anyother method please recommend me a tutorial it is for my thesis i have spended the whole week doing this

Comment: this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540004/how-to-livestream-a-webcam-to-youtube-with-ffmpeg. I think ffmpeg might be your answer.

Comment: not to youtube but on a .com website